# How to count the number of times an element appears consecutively in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that looks like this

```
ID, Order, Segment
1, 1, A
1, 2, B
1, 3, B
1, 4, C
1, 5, B
1, 6, B
1, 7, B
1, 8, B
```

Basically by ordering the data using the Order column. I would like to understand the number of consecutive B's for each of the ID's. Ideally the output I would like is

```
ID, Consec
1, 2
1, 4
```

Because the segment B appears consecutively in row 2 and 3 (2 times), and then again in row 5,6,7,8 (4 times).

The loop solution is quite obvious but would also be very slow.

Are there elegant solutions in data.table that is also fast?

P.S. The data I am dealing with has ~20 million rows.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
  DT[order(ID, Order)][, indx:=rleid(Segment)][Segment=='B',
    list(Consec=.N), by = list(indx, ID)][,indx:=NULL][]

 #    ID Consec
 #1:  1      2
 #2:  1      4
```

Or as @eddi suggested

```
 DT[order(ID, Order)][, .(Consec = .N), by = .(ID, Segment, 
              rleid(Segment))][Segment == 'B', .(ID, Consec)]
 #    ID Consec
 #1:  1      2
 #2:  1      4
```

A more memory efficient method would be to use `setorder` instead of `order` (as suggested by @Arun)

```
  setorder(DT, ID, Order)[, .(Consec = .N), by = .(ID, Segment, 
                rleid(Segment))][Segment == 'B', .(ID, Consec)]
  #   ID Consec
  #1:  1      2
  #2:  1      4
```

Comment: you don't really need to explicitly create a new column, and can do it on the fly: `DT[order(ID, Order)][, .(Consec = .N), by = .(ID, Segment, rleid(Segment))][Segment == 'B', .(ID, Consec)]`

Comment: Why do you need `order()`?

Comment: @Arun It gives a different answer without the order here `set.seed(42);
 d1 <- data.frame(ID= sample(1:4, 30, replace=TRUE), Order= sample(1:10, 30, replace=TRUE), Segment= sample(LETTERS[1:3], 30, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE); DT <- as.data.table(d1)`

Comment: @akrun, thanks. In that case I'd use `setorder()` if possible as `DT[order()][..]` would create the ordered data entirely in a new location in memory.

Comment: I asked a similar question that drew several useful responses. Worth a review:
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280948/how-can-i-analyze-the-consecutive-persistence-of-signals-1s-and-0s-in-dataset


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280948/how-can-i-analyze-the-consecutive-persistence-of-signals-1s-and-0s-in-dataset