# How to count the number of times an element appears consecutively in a table in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that looks like this

```
ID, Order, Segment
1, 1, A
1, 2, B
1, 3, B
1, 4, C
1, 5, B
1, 6, B
1, 7, B
1, 8, B
```

Basically by ordering the data using the Order column. I would like to understand the number of consecutive B's for each of the ID's. Ideally the output I would like is

```
ID, Consec
1, 2
1, 4
```

Because the segment B appears consecutively in row 2 and 3 (2 times), and then again in row 5,6,7,8 (4 times).

I can't think of a solution in SQL since there is no loop facility in SQL.

Are there elegant solutions in Teradata SQL?

P.S. The data I am dealing with has ~20 million rows.

The way to do it in R has been published here.

[How to count the number of times an element appears consecutively in a data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641792/how-to-count-the-number-of-times-an-element-appears-consecutively-in-a-data-tabl/29641859#29641859)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to do with analytic functions. While I don't know anything about teradata, quickly googling makes it appear as though it does support analytic functions.

In any case, I've tested the following in Oracle --

```
  select id,
         count(*)
    from (select x.*,
                 row_number() over(partition by id order by ord) -
                 row_number() over(partition by id, seg order by ord) as grp
            from tbl x) x
   where seg = 'B'
group by id, grp
order by grp
```

The trick is establishing the 'groups' of Bs.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ed6c/2/0

Comment: If `ord` is actually an unbroken unique sequence, you could just do `ord - row_number() over(partition by id, seg order by ord) as grp`  Also, I believe you can safely add the `seg` column to the final output by appending it to the list of columns to `group by`.

Comment: or just row_number() - row_number() over(partition by id, seg order by ord) as grp